# Crash on CLConnection::sendMessageInternal

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need help trying to figure out this crash.

I have a common crash (#1 crash, ~300 devices affected) that seems to occur when my app is checking CLLocation authorization status:

[image]

The 'start' method is as follows:

```
-(BOOL)start {
    if ([self isDenied]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        _manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _manager.delegate = self;

        if ([_manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] && [self isNotDetermined]) {
            [_manager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        } else {
            [self startUpdatingLocation];
        }
        return YES;
    }
}
```

The 'isNotDetermined' method, from which the application seems to switch to a different thread and crash, is:

```
- (BOOL)isNotDetermined {
    return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined;
}
```

Maybe also relevant, the isDenied method; according to the documentation, the CLLocationManager should not be created if the authorization status is Denied or Restricted:

```
- (BOOL)isDenied {
    return CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied;
}
```

Could it be that the app crashes because I create a CLLocationManager while the authorizationStatus is Restricted? I'd expect the crash to occur in the CLLocationManager init method in that case.

Comment: I am getting this issue in my app & since iOS v9x this crash is increasing tremendously. Can you pls provide the solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I / we have managed to find the problem. The problem was twofold:

1. stopUpdatingLocation was not called when the application entered the background.
2. When the application entered the foreground, the CLLocationManager was re-initialized, without first stopping the old instance. Two bits of code:

```c
// called in both didFinishLaunching and applicationWillEnterForeground
-(void) start {
  _manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  // other setup code
}

// Called in applicationDidEnterBackground
-(void)stop {
  // this variable was never false
  if (_updateBackgroundLocations) { 
    [_manager stopUpdatingLocation];
  }
}
```

What I did to fix it:

```c
-(void) start {
  if (_manager == nil) {
    _manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
  }
  // other setup code
}

-(void)stop {
  [_manager stopUpdatingLocation];
}
```

This fixed... several thousand crashes. They probably occurred when the application was already in the background, since we never did get complaints about frequently occurring crashes from our users.

Comment: I am seeing these same crashes, but I believe I am already doing what you outlined above. My CLLocationManager is only created once in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, I run stopUpdatingLocations in willEnterBackground, and I run startUpdatingLocations in applicationWillEnterForeground. Is there anything else you can recommend?